# Ultrapowers of ultrapowers

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters, ultrapowers

Suppose that you have some structure $S$, and you want to construct an ultrapower of cardinality $\kappa$ to obtain $S^*_\kappa$. Then, say you want to construct a new ultrapower from $S^*_\kappa$, this time of cardinality $\lambda$, where $\lambda > \kappa$, to obtain $(S^*_\kappa)^*_\lambda$.

Is the result isomorphic to something you could have gotten if you had instead just constructed a $\lambda$-cardinality ultrapower $S^*_\lambda$ directly on $S$ to begin with?

I'm pretty sure that this is undecidable in ZFC, or else it's false, due to the way that CH interacts with ultrapower isomorphisms. However, if it's undecidable and not outright false, is there some common axiom that the truth of this statement would flow from, like GCH or something even stronger, or perhaps a large cardinal axiom?

Comment: If $D$ and $E$ are ultrafilters then for any model $\mathbb{U}$, $\prod_{D\times E}\mathbb{U} \backsimeq \prod_E(\prod_D \mathbb{U})$

Comment: I cannot make sense of what you mean by the $λ$-cardinality ultrapower $S^{∗}_{λ}$. Two ultrafilters $D$ and $E$ are Rudin-Keisler equivalent if and only if $A^{D}$ and $A^{E}$ are isomorphic for each structure $A$, and one can construct many non-isomorphic ultrapowers of the same cardinality. In general, the $λ$ -cardinality ultrapower $S^{∗}_{λ}$ is not unique. Furthermore, the $λ$-cardinality ultrapower $S^{∗}_{λ}$ does not necessarily exist.

Comment: If you follow up on Mohammad Golshani's comment, be aware that the literature contains several conventions and notations for the "product" of two ultrafilters, and that this product is not commutative.  In particular, what Mohammad calls $D\times E$ seems to be what I would call $E\otimes D$.

Comment: Joseph: clarified by changing the wording a bit.

Comment: Andreas - which product is that?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia If $E$ and $D$ are ultrafilters on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, then what I call $E\otimes D$ is $\{A\subseteq X\times Y:\{x\in X:\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in A\}\in D\}\in E\}$. In other words, a subset of $X\times Y$ is large with respect to $E\otimes D$ iff $E$-almost all of its vertical sections are large with respect to $D$.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Many years late, shouldn't that be an answer?